# C# Build Solution problem with ERROR CA0055

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3, postsharp

I am trying to build my project and I am getting a weird error every time I try to build the solution.  The error is

Error   37  CA0055 : Could not load [Path to DLL].      SampleProject
Error   38  CA0052 : No targets were selected.      SampleProject

Any help would be much appreciated.

This solution is also using the following
PostSharp 2.0
Telerik
MVC 3
T4 Templates

I don't know if these contribute to anything but hopefully it is enough information.

Comment: Which exact version of PostSharp are you using?

Comment: My current verion is 2.0.8.1323

Comment: I tried an MVC 2 application and I'm able to use it. Can you post your aspect stubs and how you're declaring them to objects?

Comment: Are you using code contracts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to reformat.  I couldn't get past it any other way that I had found online or via colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using FxCop or an IDE code review plugin? Because both error code point to that.

Comment: I think the only thing I am using is Resharper 5.1

Comment: I did try that by suspending.  It didn't work the only way I was able to suppress this was to edit the csproj file and set the XML Node "RunCodeAnalysis" to false.  But that is a work around not a solution.

Comment: I would look into your installation of Resharper, because it seem to me from brief google search that it used FxCop at some point. The fact that disabling "RunCodeAnalysis" had an impact indicates even further the relation between the error and a code analysis tool.

Answer (score 0):

I also looked for reasons a long time.
If you use a console version of fxcop.
Try to use all following parameters togeather of fxcop  ("fxcop /help" for details).

/searchgac 
/assemblycomparemode:StrongNameIgnoringVersion 
/directory:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" 
/directory:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727" 
/reference:"packages\Autofac.4.0.0\lib\net451\Autofac.dll" 
/reference:"packages\Autofac.3.5.0\lib\net40\Autofac.dll"